Chapter number in the header with \chapter*
I need to display the chapter (section) name with the \chapter* (\section*) command to the header, but it display the wrong number with previous chapter (section). Now I want to remove the chapter (section) number when I use \chapter* (\section*) and other do not change.


I tried the the answer in Chapter name in the header with \chapter*, but it don't work on my example. The minimal reproducible example:
%! TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{blindtext, lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} 
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LO]{
    \ifnum\value{section}>0
        \S
    \fi
    \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
        \chaptername\ \thechapter.\ 
    \fi
    \leftmark}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[5-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1.1}

\lipsum[10-20]

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 2.1}

\lipsum[5-10]

\backmatter

\chapter*{Appendix}
\chaptermark{Appendix}

\lipsum[5-10]

\section*{Unnumber section in Appendix}
\sectionmark{Unnumber section in Appendix}

\lipsum[5-10]

\section{Another section in Appendix}

\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}

How can I fix this?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

you are explicitly adding the value of the chapter counter into the header with \thechapter. in the appendix, the test you use is always true, so this code is always added.

Why not just redefine the marks as appropriate? You basically want three definitions: one for the front matter, one for the main matter and one (the same as the first) for the back matter.
You also need to increase \headheight as fancyhdr complains loudly that it is too small. If you use a package for page layout, you should use its facilities rather than interfering directly as I do below.
To keep things tidy, you can hook the redefinitions onto the relevant \mainmatter and \backmatter commands, as shown below, so everything stays together in the preamble.
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{blindtext, lipsum}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.7pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.7pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}%
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}%
\AddToHook {cmd/mainmatter/before} {%
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ #1}{}}%
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\S \thesection\ #1}}%
}
\AddToHook {cmd/backmatter/before} {%
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}%
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}%
  \setcounter{section}{0)% but I think this should be automatic?
  % this works, but makes numbering indistinguishable from chapter numbering
  % \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}%
  % substitute an appropriate letter for the document language and use something like this?
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}%
  % or use A, B, C etc.?
  % \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}%
  % or I, II, III etc.?
  % \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[5-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter O}

\section{Section 1.1}

\lipsum[10-20]

\chapter{Chapter T}

\section{Section 2.1}

\lipsum[5-10]

\backmatter

\chapter*{Appendix}
\chaptermark{Appendix}

\lipsum[5-10]

\section*{Unnumber section in Appendix}
\sectionmark{Unnumber section in Appendix}

\lipsum[5-10]

\section{Another section in Appendix}

\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}


Thanks your suggestion and answer. I find \section{Another section in Appendix} part is still wrong number after previous chapter. Maybe I should not use \section{} after \backmatter or just \setcounter{chapter}{0} and \setcounter{section}{0}.

@Abel if you have numbered sections in the appendix, you probably want \renewcommand{\thesection}{\S \arabic{section}.} to get rid of the chapter number. setting it to 0 will get you numbering like 0.1 which isn't great either. hang on.

@Abel I've put some possibilities in the code as I'm not sure what you want to do here.

Thanks a lot. That's what I want, \renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}.
